# Scoring scale object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started working with Unity platform just a few days ago. I want to create and object like this one: (http://www.bankingsense.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/credit-score-ratings.png) where the user will choose the appropriate answer. Each option will generate a different score that should be stored for later use.
Can anyone give me some tips ad guidelines to this?
Thank you very much!
Vânia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very simple. use one image as the scale background. use another image as the pointer. set the pivot and anchor of the pointer at the position where you want to rotate it. use transform.Rotate() in your code to rotate the pointer.